# how can I work around the jComboBox dependant dropdown Null error without writing hundreds of lines per choice?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox

The issue I'm getting is every time it does .removeAllItems() I get an error that makes the dropdowns not work. The error is
`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "Object.equals(Object)" because the return value of "javax.swing.JComboBox.getSelectedItem()" is null`

I've been working on trying to make a code where I have 3 drop down menus that change based off the first 2.

So it's alot like

```
Country dropdown (United States, Canada, Mexico)

if (Country.getSelectedItem().equals("United States"))
{
  Label1.setText("States");
  Dropdown1.removeAllItems();
  Dropdown1.addItem(" ");
  Dropdown1.addItem("Alabama");
  Dropdown1.addItem("Wisconsin");
  Dropdown1.addItem("Maine");
}

if (Dropdown1.selectedItem().equals("Alabama")
  {

  if (Label2.getText().equals("Towns")
    {
    }
  else
    {
    Label2.setLabel("Towns");
    Dropdown2.removeAllItems();
    Dropdown2.addItem(" ");
    Dropdown2.addItem("Mobile");
    }
  }
else
  {
  }

if (Dropdown2.getSelectedItem().equals("Mobile")
  {
    if (Dropdown1.getSelectedItem().equals("Alabama")
    {
      Info1.setText("Name");
      Info1_sub.setText("Mobile");
      Info2.setText("Size");
      Info2_sub.setText("City");
      Info3.setText("Area code");
      Info3_sub.setText("251");
      Info4.setText("Personal Contacts");
      Info4_sub.setText("124");
    }
    else 
    {
    }
  }
else
  {
  }
```

Edit:

SOLVED!!!!
I was playing with more codes and figured out if I added in a while loop it'll do exactly what I want.

the code for others will be as follows.

Combobox1 items = 1, 2, 3, 4
Combobox2 items = Test 1, Test 2, Test3

```
{
  while (Combobox2.getItemCount() > 1)
  {
    Combobox2.removeItemAt(1);
  }
  Combobox2.addItem("Real1");
  Combobox2.addItem("Real2");
}

Thank you everyone who tried to help and so much for the ideas!
```

Comment: yes I do understand the problem. However I can't find a solution other than manually removing every line that's added from the dropdown to then add the new ones in. I was just seeing if anyone had an idea that didn't involve me writing a couple hundred more lines of code for every selection that I add.

Thank you though Arsh Coder

Comment: use something like :- `if ((Dropdown2.getSelectedItem()!=null) && Dropdown2.getSelectedItem().equals("Mobile")){     //do your work here                   }`

Comment: Please make sure to follow [ask] on posting

Comment: @ArshCoder I tried your idea. In the Apache IDE netbeans software I'm using to help assist in my coding. It throws a couple more errors doing that and renders the whole application unusable.

```Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable code - <identifier> expected```

is the error I get

Comment: I realized if there was a way to delete all but 0. Kind of like ```Dropdown2.removeItemAt(1);``` it would work as well. But with the nature of how the program will run. I wont know how many items need to be deleted at this point in production.

Comment: @kleopatra I will try to. Sorry. However I'm fairly new to this level of java so I'm not familiar with Java naming conventions

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing .removeAllItems()
I created a while loop to remove the items I wanted gone.